# Handling missing value in Python Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this lambda function statement

```
def do_math_operation(operand, x, y):
    return {
        'add': lambda x, y: x + y,
        'subtract': lambda x, y: x - y,
        'divide': lambda x, y: x / y,
        'multiply': lambda x, y: x * y
    }.get(operand, "Operation not present")(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(do_math_operation('add', 20, 4))
```

And everything works fine when I supply the expected word "add/subtract/divide/multiply"

In some instance, if I supply a value not present in the list like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(do_math_operation('square', 20, 4))
```

I am getting an exception

```
    }.get(operand, "Operation not present")(x, y)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Maybe because the call to get returns a string and is not a function.  But I am not sure how to properly handle this error in my code.

Maybe how can I raise an exception if the value is not present. I can limit the value to "add/subtract/divide/multiply" but I wanted my function to be intelligent enough to handle this scenario.

Any hints?

Comment: Instead of `.get(operand, ...)`, use `[operand]`; this will raise a `KeyError`, which you can handle or simply leave unhandled.

Comment: Doing that I think will just change the error to "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: No, because accessing missing keys through subscript *raises a `KeyError`.*

Comment: If you use key-based access, it will indeed be a `KeyError` on a missing key. The `TypeError` occurs because you're using `some_dict.get(key_name, default_return)`, so you're circumventing the error of a missing key and getting back whatever your default was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is explicitly to suppress `KeyError`s should the key not exist. Instead of using `.get`, access the key using subscript syntax:

```
return {
    'add': lambda x, y: x + y,
    'subtract': lambda x, y: x - y,
    'divide': lambda x, y: x / y,
    'multiply': lambda x, y: x * y
}[operand](x, y)
```

This raises a `KeyError`. If you wish, you can handle that, inside or outside your `do_math_operation` function:

```
try:
    ...
except KeyError:
    print('Invalid operand', operand)
```

To offer a really nice API for your function, you may want to turn that `KeyError` into another very clear error:

```
def do_math_operation(operand, x, y):
    try:
        return {
            ...
        }[operand](x, y)
    except KeyError as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid operand '{operand}'") from e
```

[`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) makes a lot of sense for the caller:

```
try:
    do_math_operation('square', 1, 2)
except ValueError:
    print(':(')
```

You could go even more overboard and define your own unique error type which is unmistakable for any other problems which may occur during this function's execution:

```
class InvalidOperatorError(ValueError):
     pass
```

```
    ...
except KeyError as e:
    raise InvalidOperatorError(operator) from e
```

Comment: Yeah I think I got the point here.  Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation.  It is an exceptional case so handle it exceptionally.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent your error-case as a lambda as well:

```
def do_math_operation(operand, x, y):
    return {
        'add': lambda x, y: x + y,
        'subtract': lambda x, y: x - y,
        'divide': lambda x, y: x / y,
        'multiply': lambda x, y: x * y
    }.get(operand, lambda x, y: "operation not present")(x, y)

print(do_math_operation("add", 2, 2))
print(do_math_operation("square", 2, 3))
```

Result:

```
4
operation not present
```

Comment: Oh haven't thought of this one.. cool solution so everything gets package in my lambda function itself.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend returning an error message as a valid return value from a function that's supposed to do math.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution (with minimal code change) would be `try/except`.

```
def do_math_operation(operand, x, y):
    try:
        return {
            'add': lambda x, y: x + y,
            'subtract': lambda x, y: x - y,
            'divide': lambda x, y: x / y,
            'multiply': lambda x, y: x * y
        }.get(operand)(x, y)
    except TypeError:
        return "Operation not found"
```

Comment: Yes, it will, that's why I put it in a `try` block. Every exception of the type specifed in the `except` block that is raised in the `try` block will be caught. More about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: Ohh okay, I wrapped it around the try except so that is where the error gets caught.  I was thinking of having it included in the function definition itself.

Comment: `TypeError` may be raised by problems other than a non-existing operand, it's pretty yucky looking for *that* as the indicator.

Comment: I didn't say it was perfect... it just required very little change, and in a function this small it really isn't a problem. But in general, I agree